# responsiveness not working when viewing in phone

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a website https://hidden-woodland-20166.herokuapp.com/ and everything is working fine when building it in vs code. All nav responsive features are responding correctly like the nav links are replaced with the hamburger menu when the browser size is in max-width 764px and the nav-links slides from the right when I click the hamburger menu.

After deploying it in heroku, I tried viewing the website in my phone but the nav-bar is all messed up. Its like the media query is not working at all.

Anyone have an idea why this is happenning?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by messed up?

Comment: External links are useless for future visitors, please include [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For me, it looks fine when I inspect it (chrome dev tools), if you're talking about the black hamburger menu (right side).

Comment: Your nav menu works correctly, but icon is hidden. There is an error you can see in developer console: menu icon svg is missing. Perhaps you hotlinked icon directly from flaticon?

Comment: yeah its fine when you view it in desktop browser. The problem happens when you view it in your mobile device. Reducing the desktop browser size  doesn't show the problem.

Comment: yeah its a url from flaticon. Should I replacing the menu icon with a local one?

Comment: It works fine on my phone (Safari on iphone 12). The menu icon is missing, but tapping on the general vicinity displays the menu. It is a bit too large for the height of the screen but it's there.

Comment: I replaced the hamburger icon. The only problem now is that the sidebar should be overfolow: hidden.
@media screen and (max-width: 764px) {
 body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
} 

I can still see the sidebar when I swipe to the left on my phone.

Comment: the `overflow-x` `hdden` should be on the body and also give the body a `max-width` of `100vw`

Comment: @SpicySauce I used some js to resolve your issue, check the answer it will explain what i did

Answer (score 0):

I set the display of the menu to `none` only when it is off the page. You need to use `setTimeout` when showing the menu however, because otherwise the browser will try to apply a `transform`ation to the menu while its `display` is `none`, and this will result in the animation being instantaneous and not smooth. Here is the script I changed:

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

  //   toggle animation
  toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //hamburger animation
    toggle.classList.toggle("toggle-active");
    //   Nav animation
    
    if(!nav.classList.contains("nav-active")) {
      nav.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => nav.style.display = "none", 500);
    }
    setTimeout(() => nav.classList.toggle("nav-active"), 100);
  });
};
navSlide();
```